TypeError: 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable
Here's my code. I'm just messing around and trying to make a simple Reddit bot but there are SO MANY ERRORS. i've spent days just fixing the errors... Can someone help me not only fix this error but prevent me from getting more errors? I just want it TO WORK!!!!
load_dotenv()
    
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=os.environ.get("sk-proj-v4nIq4gmEPrZc0rDhWxVT3BlbkFJf0dgtD1uvKUkXwCzEspz"),
    )

    # This is the default and can be omitted

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

detailed_prompt = """

try:
    client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        training_file="file-abc123",
    )
except openai.APIConnectionError as e:
    print("The server could not be reached")
    print(e.__cause__)  # an underlying Exception, likely raised within httpx.
except openai.RateLimitError as e:
    print("A 429 status code was received; we should back off a bit.")
except openai.APIStatusError as e:
    print("Another non-200-range status code was received")
    print(e.status_code)
    print(e.response)

# Function to generate response using OpenAI
def generate_response(prompt):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are George Kailas, an expert in investing and the CEO of Prospero."},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ],
        max_tokens=150,
        temperature=0.7
    )
    return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()
    



reddit_post = "What are some good resources to learn about stock market investing?"
response = generate_response(detailed_prompt.replace("[Your Reddit Post Here]", reddit_post))
print(response)

Thanks in advance for your help.
I just debugged and then a new error would arise.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please revoke the API key you leaked in your question. Use the OpenAI dashboard and revoke it. API keys should be kept private.
